# Not able to fetch title from API

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import axios, {isCancel, AxiosError} from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    const FetchApi= async() => {
        const uri = 'https://crypto-news16.p.rapidapi.com/news/top/1';
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'APIkey',
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'crypto-news16.p.rapidapi.com'
              }
        };
        try {
            const response = await fetch(uri, options);
            var result = await response.text();
            result=>result.json();
            setData(result)
            console.log(data);
          } 
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Welcome To The Application</Text>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}>
                <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:30}}>{data}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={FetchApi} style={{backgroundColor:'blue',
                                                         width:'90%',margin:20,
                                                         alignItems:'center',
                                                         justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <Text style={{color:'white',padding:5}}>
                    Fetch
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );
};

export default App;
```

This is my code and I am not able to access the property title of the API server it shows error "undefined" and if I remove the title from try catch block as:

```js
try {
    const response = await fetch(uri, options);
    var result = await response.text();
    result=>result.json();
    console.log(result);
} 
catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

it is running perfectly and giving me all the content but if I wanted to fetch the title only it is not.

I wanted to fetch the title only for the above said problem.